# Recommended approach to leveraging Shopify login to provision access to certain content in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, authentication, shopify

We use Shopify Plus for our Ecom but Wordpress for our content, we provide a massive library of videos, posts, tutorials, etc.. for our product. We would like to paywall a bit of this content however and serve it up only to certain Shopify customer types.

Trying to avoid managing/syncing two accounts per customer (one in WP and Shopify)

Any suggestions?  Would JSON web tokens work?

Comment: Utilising shopify JSON API will be the way to go on this one, it’s a reasonably straightforward job for a good WP dev, but quite a big task. More work than what fits in a stack overflow answer!